# Possible to remove cluster from 2.4.8 server and import it on a fresh 2.5 server?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, rancher

due to a wrong installation method (single node) we would like to migrate our existing kubernetes cluster to a newer and HA-rancher-kubernetes cluster.

Can someone tell me if it’s safe to do following:

- remove (previously imported) cluster from our 2.4.8 single-node rancher installation
- register this cluster again on our new kubernetes-managed 2.5 rancher-cluster?

We already tried this with our development cluster and it worked fine, the only thing which was necessary to do was to:

- create user/admin accounts again
- reassign all namespaces to the corresponding rancher projects

Would be nice to get some more opinions on this, right now it looks more or less safe :smiley:

Also does someone know what happens if one kubernetes cluster is registered/imported to two rancher instances at the same time (like 2.4.8 and 2.5 at the same time) - I know its probably really a bad Idea - just want to get a better understanding if I’m wrong :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give some feedback after we solved it by our selfes:

We removed the old installation and imported the cluster again in the new installation, worked fine wihtout problems.

We also had another migration, where we moved again since our old rancher installation didnt work anymore (on a managed kubernetes cluster, which is not recommended) and wasnt also reachable anymore.

we just imported the cluster into the new rancher installation, without removing it from the old one. Everything worked fine also, except that the projects-namespace associations were broken and we had to reassign all namespaces to new projects again. Also somehow our alerting is still not working correctly, the notification emails still point to our old rancher installation domain, even though we changed all config files which we found.